# Get parent stack layout height after setting text to label for y positioning - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My code looks like this

```
<StackLayout x:Name="TooltipLabelLayout">
   <Label x:Name="TooltipLabel" />
</StackLayout>
```

I set the **TooltipLabel** text dynamically say

```
TooltipLabel.Text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ultricies, elit nec facilisis tristique, erat justo consectetur leo, ac tristique diam nisi non libero. Pellentesque"
```

How to get the actual **TooltipLabelLayout.Height** immediately after setting the label text.

Comment: **TooltipLabelLayout.Height** or **TooltipLabelLayout.HeightRequest** is not working for you?

Comment: no. TooltipLabelLayout.Height will work second time after it gets Label text gets rendered first time.

Comment: I overriden **OnSizeAllocated** method which gave correct result.

Comment: oh. can you provide me a example please. OnSizeAllocated can be overriden  only for page rite?

Comment: sorry i checked wrong result, yes you are right it's for page only, Forgot to comment here